# ActionController::Caching::Sweeper vs ActionController::Caching::Sweeping

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any co-relation between 
ActionController::Caching::Sweeper and ActionController::Caching::Sweeping

When i see doc for [ActionController::Caching::Sweeping](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionController/Caching/Sweeping),

I see **ActionController::Caching::Sweeper** documentation

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you haven't noticed, you are looking at a very outdated documentation. Sweepers were part of observers, and they have been extracted out from Rails on the Rails 4 major version. The documentation you are pointing at is for Rails 2.3.8 (notice the version in the URL), which was [released in April 2010](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions) (almost 5 years ago).

That said, you can check yourself by browsing the [new repository for Rails observers](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers/tree/v0.1.2/lib/rails/observers/action_controller/caching).

This is the [`sweeping.rb` file](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers/blob/v0.1.2/lib/rails/observers/action_controller/caching/sweeping.rb). `Sweeping` is the `Module` that was mixed inside `ActionController` to enable the sweeper capabilities into a controller. The `Sweeper` instead is the actual class that implement a sweeper and inherits from `ActiveRecord::Observer`.

The documentation is the same, because the documentation block is attached to the `Sweeping` module and it covers the module functionalities, including how a `Sweeper` is used.